# How to communicate between two instances of python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, security, communication

### Problem

Two python scripts need to communicate with each other.

…But there is a little problem. One is a service (written in python) that gets called when user's computer boots up (core) and the second gets called when ever user wants (front-end) also written in python and front-end techs.
So we have at least two different instances of python interpreter.

### What I tried

Using files → Not secure, content is readable by any process.

Using Socket → Firewall problems, Not very great at security.

Using pipes (`os.pipe()`) → Is not shared between different python interpreters. (same version), better security (It's easier to control add-ons then every process on system)

Is there any other way to do that that I haven't tried or an advice that may help, a standard library function or class, a library or something?

If the front-end calls the core again it will nearly take 15 seconds (let's not talk about this, please). I'm not going to let my user wait 15 seconds to start just the core. This will result in removal of application and some non-kind words. `:)`

#### Maybe useful

The communication has to be capable to transfer more than thousands bytes.
It would be great if it is also python2 compatible.

### UPDATE AFTER MARTINEAU'S ANSWER

### Solution

Thanks to [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64453011/14294250) that made writing a code-snippet about solution possible for me. The code snippet:

```py
>>> from multiprocessing import shared_memory
>>> s = shared_memory.SharedMemory("NAME", create=True)
>>> s.buf[0] = 5
>>> # Now in another python shell
>>> import multiprocessing.shared_memory as sm
>>> sm.SharedMemory("NAME", create=False)
>>> s.buf[0] 
5
```

Comment: thanks for the edit @martineau now looks better. but still no answer ):

Comment: I'm no expert at interprocess communication. One thing you might try is [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html). The docs say "…one process can create a shared memory block with a particular name and a different process can attach to that same shared memory block using that same name."

Comment: thanks for the try. but the problem is that the first python interpreter (the service) doesn't run the front-end. so I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: I was thinking the service could create the shared memory and give it unique name — which the front-end could look for when it's run (and specify `create=False`).

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe the answer. Let me check it. If it worked I will let you know. Then you can write it as an answer.

Comment: Worked ! Thanks. you made my day. please write it as answer. so others can use it, too

Comment: If you needed help (never mind me, nothing offensive here) I have a small code that you may add it to your answer as an example. just tell me to write it in the comments

Comment: Fell free to add your code to my answer (or add it a separate answer which is allowed here — you can still accept my answer) Yet another possiblity would be for you to [edit] your question and add an update to the end of it showing what you did.

Comment: I would liked to add it to your answer. but stackoverflow ain't letting me. so I will add it to my question itself. with a link of your answer

Comment: Oops, forgot about that restriction. Your alternative sounds good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might try is [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html). Its docs say "…one process can create a shared memory block with a particular name and a different process can attach to that same shared memory block using that same name.

To elaborate a bit more: Have the service create a shared memory instance and give it unique name, and then have the front-end look for one that has that name whenever it's run (specifying `create=False` on the call when it does so).

Hope that's clear and enough detail for you.